# validar dato ingresado en mi db

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hola estoy tratando de validar un dato que se ingresa en mi formulario , ese dato es un numero único entonces estoy tratando de cuando ingrese un numero que ya esta en la db arroje un mensaje que ese numero ya esta en uso dejo un poco de mi código si me pueden ayudar.

```
    <?php

include('db.php');

if (isset($_POST['guardarNumero'])) {
  //aqui necesito validar 
  $numero = $_POST['numero'];
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
  $rut = $_POST['rut'];
  $fechaNacimiento = $_POST['fechaNacimiento'];
  $telefono = $_POST['fono'];
  $correo = $_POST['correo'];
  $ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];
  $club = $_POST['club'];
  $team = $_POST['team'];
  $elegirCat = $_POST['elegirCategoria'];
  $numeroContacto = $_POST['numeroContacto'];
  $nombreContacto = $_POST['nombreContacto'];
  $query = "INSERT INTO reservas(nroPiloto,nombre, rut,fechaNacimiento,fono,correo,ciudad,club,team,categoria,telefonoContacto,nombreCon) VALUES ('$numero', '$nombre','$rut','$fechaNacimiento','$telefono','$correo','$ciudad','$club','$team','$elegirCat','$numeroContacto','$nombreContacto')";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

  if(!$result) {
    die("Query Failed.");
  }

  $_SESSION['message'] = 'Piloto Ingresado Exitosamente!';
  $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'success';
  header('Location: index.php');

}


?>
```

Comment: ¿Y dónde compruebas si ese dato ya existe? Porque no se ve ningún `SELECT` con el que haces la comprobación ¿Has definido una clave `UNIQUE` en la tabla `reservas`?

Comment: Una forma es crear un índice de unicidad para ese campo en tu tabla de la DB. Al intentar guardar un valor existente, es la DB la que te arrojará un error o excepción y tú simplemente manejas dicho error para mostrar el mensaje apropiado. Hacerlo así te asegura la atomicidad de la operación, evitando que debas hacer una consulta previa para determinar si ya existe un registro con ese valor en el campo. Saludos